# Angularjs displaying json in Rails

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to display a list of my donors - the html is:

```
<div class="panel">
<header>
 <h1> Donor Information </h1>
</header>

<div class="content">
 <div ng-app="Donor">
  <div ng-controller="DonorCtrl">

  <ul>
   <li ng-repeat="donor in donors">{{donors.name_last | json}}</li>
  </ul>

   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

My Donor_controller.js is this:

```
var app;
app = angular.module("Donor", ["ngResource"]);

app.factory("Donors", [
   "$resource", function($resource) {
    return $resource("/donors", {}, {
        update: {
            method: "PUT"
        }
    });
  }
]);

app.factory("Donor", [
"$resource", function($resource) {
    return $resource("/donors/:id", {
        id: "@id"
    }, {
        update: {
            method: "GET"
        }
    });
  }
]);

this.DonorCtrl = [
 "$scope", "Donor", "Donors", function($scope, Donor, Donors) {
    var donor;
    $scope.donor = Donor.query();
    $scope.donors = Donors;
    $scope.addDonor = function() {};
    donor = Donor.save($scope.newDonor)(function() {
        return $scope.donors.push(donor);
    });
    return $scope.newDonor = {};
  }
];
```

I am returning from my rails app via donors/1.json this:

```
{
  "donor": {
  "id": 1,
  "tools_id": null,
  "first_name": "Billy",
  "last_name": "Bullard"
  }
}
```

I get a list of dots when I view and it shows this on inspection (repeated):

```
<li ng-repeat="donor in donors" class="ng-scope ng-binding"></li>
```

How do I go from the json coming from Rails to the list of names in Angularjs?

Answer (score 2):

You should remove `| json` from your bind and you want the `donor`'s lastname, not the `donors`':

```html
<li ng-repeat="donor in donors">{{donor.name_last}}</li>
```

**Update 1**

Also, you should have `$scope.donors = Donors.query();` in your controller, not `$scope.donor = ...`.

Comment: additional note...`json` filter is for pretty print of object or array, typically only used for development debugging

Comment: Removed json {{donor.last_name}}  get: `TypeError: Cannot read property '$id' of undefined donor` the model for the repeat shows:
`[ undefined, { 
0: d
 } , { 
0: i
 } , { 
0: v
 } , { 
0:  
 } , `

Comment: What are you returning for `/donors/`? Also, I just noticed that your array of donors is being saved saved to `$scope.donor`, not `donors`. And why are you setting `$scope.donors = Donors`? Shouldn't it be `$scope.donors = Donor.query();` only?

Comment: now have '$scope.donors = Donors.query();' same thing it returns basically an empty list - Actually in looking at the returned list in batarang the list is the html in my form { 
donor:  { 
0: d
$$hashKey: 006
 } 
 }  this d is the start of div - weird

Comment: Pretty weird, but what you see in Network response? Are you gettin an **array** of donors? Is you server returning an `application/json`?

Comment: it is returning donors.json   donors/1.json returns a json object for a single donor - I am thinking it is in my factory

Comment: Are you sure you're getting an **array** with the children donors? It's not an object with nested donors, is it?